# How to get a untyped ObservableCollection from a DataContext?

Tags: c#, windows-8, observablecollection, untyped-variables

I need to get a untyped QueryableCollection from a DataContext to query it. I have the following code:

```
printAbleListView = (ListView) printObject.FindName("printAbleListView");
// Here I like to have something like ObservableCollection<Object>
ObservableCollection<Journal> allItems = (ObservableCollection<Journal>) printAbleListView.DataContext;

// Add the page to the page preview collection
for (int i = 0; i <= (allItems.Count()/30); i++)
{
  printAbleListView.DataContext = null;
  printAbleListView.DataContext = allItems.Skip(30 * i).Take(30);
  document.SetPreviewPage((i + 1), printObject);
}
```

The goal is to print out any ListView in a Metro-Style Windows 8 app. Currently it is typed to the `Journal` DataType, but I like to have it untyped so the function can be reused for every ListView, not only for the `Journal` ones. Hw can i archive this?

Comment: maybe you just want to make the function generic?

Comment: maybe, but I don't know how. Can you give a example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example:

```
void GeneratePreview<T>(int itemsPerPage)
{
    var printAbleListView = (ListView)printObject.FindName("printAbleListView");
    var allItems = (ObservableCollection<T>)printAbleListView.DataContext;

    // Add the page to the page preview collection
    for (int i = 0; i <= (allItems.Count()/itemsPerPage); i++)
    {
      printAbleListView.DataContext =
              allItems.Skip(itemsPerPage * i).Take(itemsPerPage);
      document.SetPreviewPage((i + 1), printObject);
    }
}
```

---

For untyped access, you can actually use the fact that `ObservableCollection<T>` supports non-generic `ICollection`:

```
void GeneratePreview(int itemsPerPage)
{
    var printAbleListView = (ListView)printObject.FindName("printAbleListView");
    var allItems = (ICollection)printAbleListView.DataContext;

    var slice = new List<object>(itemsPerPage); // cannot use ArrayList for Win8 apps
    var pageNo = 1;
    foreach (var item in allItems)
    {            
        slice.Add(item);
        if (slice.Count % itemsPerPage == 0)
        {
            // flush
            printAbleListView.DataContext = slice;
            document.SetPreviewPage(pageNo, printObject);
            // and restart
            pageNo++;
            slice.Clear();
        }
    }
    if (slice.Count != 0) // flush the rest
    {
        printAbleListView.DataContext = slice;
        document.SetPreviewPage(pageNo, printObject);
    }
    // clean up
    printAbleListView.DataContext = null;
}
```

Comment: thx, I will try this out. To your question, basicly I want the ListView to just show 30 entrys on each iteration. Is ther an easier way?

Comment: @Jan: well, but the code will pass all the iterations without waiting, you'll always get the last one. I'll modify the code, wait a minute...

Comment: @Jan: oh, I think I see the logic. Do you mean that `document.SetPreviewPage` takes a snapshot of the `printObject` at each iteration?

Comment: Yes, the `printObject` should be a snapshot of 30 items of the ListView to print it out. Each iteration is one page. This work fine, but I want it untyped. I still have to call your function typed (e.g. `GeneratePreview<Journal>(30);`). Is there any possibility to get the type and pass it to the generic function. Something like `GeneratePreview<printAbleListView.Items.GetType()>(30);` ?

Comment: @Jan: added version with untyped access. For untyped version, no LINQ facilities are available, no needed to restructure the logic a little.

Comment: Sorry ArrayList seems to be not supported in Metro Apps. But I got it working. You pointed me in the right direction. I'am using `List<object> allItems = printAbleListView.Items.ToList();` and it works! Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Jan: thanks, I've updated the answer for the future reference.